# unable to make a service after getting responese from google address api using angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3, angular6

I am integrating google address API in my Angular 6 application. So I have copied the code to my `ts` and changed to TypeScript format. The API call is happening successfully. The result are also populating  but only constrain is I can't assign the value to angular model. I tried to pass value to a function to make service call. I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: this.addressUpdated is not a function

```
  addressUpdated(val: any): void {
      console.log(val)
  }
  fillInAddress() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      let outputdata: any = {};
      for (var component in componentForm) {
          // document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          // document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
              var addressValue = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
              // (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(addressType)).value=val;
              //document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
              //this.addressDetails[addressType]=val;
              switch (addressType) {
                  case 'street_number':
                  case 'route':
                      {
                          //statements; 
                          outputdata.street = addressValue;
                          break;
                      }
                  case 'locality':
                      {
                          outputdata.city = addressValue;
                          break;
                      }
                  case 'administrative_area_level_1':
                      {
                          outputdata.state = addressValue;
                          break;
                      }
                  case 'country':
                      {
                          outputdata.country = addressValue;
                          break;
                      }
                  case 'postal_code':
                      {
                          outputdata.zip_code = addressValue;
                          break;
                      }

              }
              console.log(addressType + ": " + addressValue);
          }
      }
      this.addressUpdated(outputdata);
  }
```

I tried to append the value to input text box

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(component)).value = '';
```

but got this error

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: I can't see this.upsateaddress in the above code.where it is used?

Comment: sorry, the method name is addressUpdated

Comment: Did you try importing the types for google maps? npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev, this might give you an idea of what is going on. Link to GitHub project: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/googlemaps

Comment: This doesn't look like a google-maps-api problem but rather like a misconfigured angular-app or some basic mistake in using typescript. Please provide the full class and do not only update the code in your question but compare with your real code.

Comment: What is calling `fillInAddress()` method? Maybe that's happening from outside angular and thus the method is not defined.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform. You can find the fillInAddress() method flow in the sample given by google.